# Raspberry pi pico with circuitpython code.py not running

Tags: pi-pico, circuitpython

I used [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_f9p-_JWZw) tutorial to create to run `circuitpython` on a `Raspberry pi pico`. I'm not trying to make a back USB as it's shown in the video, but I figured this tutorial was very good so I used it to learn how to run `circuitpython` on a `Raspberry pi pico`. I installed `circuitpython` on the drive the `adafruit_hid` folder, inside the `lib` folder and put the code bellow in `code.py`.

**Code:**

```
def log_text(text):
    with open('Log.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text + '\n')
log_text("Code is working")
```

I also created the `Log.txt` file right where `code.py` was and connected the pi again, but there was still nothing in the `Log.txt` file, it's not working. I tried many things like using different cable or USB ports but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you import storage?  This example may be more on point https://learn.adafruit.com/cpu-temperature-logging-with-circuit-python/writing-to-the-filesystem

Comment: Yes, now its working. Can you explain why exactly does this need to be done?

Comment: The short answer is because there is no OS on the Pico. For the longer answer  read this https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/storage/index.html and https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-storage

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug circuitpy is to download rshell on a linux machine.

```
pip install rshell
```

from there run `rshell` (make sure you have appropriate privileges to reach /dev files) and then connect to the pico with the command

```
connect serial /dev/ttyACM0
```

or

```
connect serial /dev/ttyACM1
```

depending on which port your pico is connected.
After that run `repl` to access the python interpreter inside the pico. And there you could run your code line by line to see which line fails also try the following snippet:

```
import time
import digitalio
import board

with digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.LED) as led:
  led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT
  led.value = True
  time.sleep(5)
```

This will turn on the LED as the code runs. LED is the best feedback when working with embedded devices.